# Difference between awswrangler and boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-data-wrangler

I have use boto3 to connect with aws services through python code. Recently I came across awswrangler library which has similar functionality as boto3. What is the difference between both.Can you explain with example like in which scenario we should use which one?

Comment: awswrangler is basically boto + pandas

Answer (score 12):

The **AWS SDK for Python (Boto3)** provides a Python API for AWS infrastructure services. Using the SDK for Python, you can build applications on top of Amazon S3, Amazon EC2, Amazon DynamoDB, and more

**AWS Data Wrangler** is an open-source Python library that enables you to focus on the transformation step of ETL by using familiar Pandas transformation commands and relying on abstracted functions to handle the extraction and load steps

[Boto3](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)

[AWS Data Wrangler](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/optimize-python-etl-by-extending-pandas-with-aws-data-wrangler/)

Comment: Note that "AWS Data Wrangler" now goes by the name "AWS SDK for pandas," though the package is still named `awswrangler` for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score -1):

A notable difference is that you can't read files from Amazon DynamoDB with the current version of AWS Data Wrangler (2.10.0)

Check the AWS Data Wrangler GitHub repository to see if there have been any changes - [AWS Data Wrangler Github Repo](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-data-wrangler)

Or the Data Wrangler documentation on AWS's site -
[AWS Data Wrangler Documentation](https://aws-data-wrangler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#dynamodb)